Identify this movie about a book-cover designer meeting a woman writer after their one night stand
A book-cover designer(works with his friend/flatmate on selling book covers) meeting a woman writer after their one night stand (he designed a cover for her book, while not knowing it is her that he slept with the previous night). Relatively new (year wise) movie.
I watched it in english language at my friends place a year or two ago, the action took place in NY (or in one of the major cities of the US). Already skimmed through IMDB and various other indexed lists of movies without success. Somebody died in the woman-writers family and the main character failed at comforting her (I don't remember properly)

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

I watched it in english language at my friends place a year or two ago, the action took place in NY (or in one of the major cities of the US). Already skimmed through IMDB and various other indexed lists of movies without success. Somebody died in the woman-writers family and the main character failed at comforting her (I don't remember properly)

Feel free to add any additional information into the question.

Sounds like That Awkward Moment (2014), where Jason (Zac Efron) plays a book cover designer who has a one night stand with Ellie (Imogen Poots) and shortly after has to design a book cover for her. Here's the trailer:




Thank you very much ! And now I see that it was opened in my of my tabs in IMDB, my bad for not being attentive enough to read the plot description heh.
